# Solve for $x$: $\ln(x)-x=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this equation for $x$?
$$\ln(x)-x=-1 $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try plugging in some integers.

Comment: Bro.. Think graphically. Thats the only hint I'm giving you.

Comment: I'd rather say that you cannot identify a polynomial equation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x):=\ln(x)-x+1$ is defined in $(0,\infty)$, it is continuous, and by its derivative $\dfrac1x-1$, it has a single extremum at $x=1$. As $f(1)=0$, this is the one and only root (which is double).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x) = \ln x - x$.Take $f'(x)$ and analyse the sign of it over $x > 1$ and $0< x < 1$.So $x =1$ is the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beside inspection as Alex S commented, consider the function and its derivatives $$f(x)=\log(x)-x+1$$ $$f'(x)=\frac 1x -1$$ $$f''(x)=-\frac 1{x^2}< 0$$ The first derivative cancels when $x=1$. For this value, $f(1)=0$ and the second derivative test shows that this point is the maximum.

Then $\cdots ???$